# JDBI 3 Nested object with lombok

Tags: lombok, jdbi, jdbi3

First of all, I already tried this [JDBI 3: Nested SQLObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65787198/jdbi-3-nested-sqlobject) and it didn't work

I'm trying basically the same thing as the other person, to gather some nested objects in jdbi 3 but using `RegisterConstructorMapper` instead.

This is my code:

ClassA.java

```
@Value
@AllArgsConstructor
@Jacksonized
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class ClassA {

    @Nested
    ClassB classB;
    String someString;
}
```

ClassB.java

```
@Value
@AllArgsConstructor
@Jacksonized
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class ClassB {
    Long id;
}
```

The code in my dao:

```
@SqlQuery("""
SELECT
    a.some_string as someString,
    b.id as b_id
FROM table_a a
INNER JOIN table_b b on a.b_id = b.id
WHERE a.id = :id
""")
@RegisterConstructorMapper(value = ClassB.class, prefix = "b")
@RegisterConstructorMapper(ClassA.class)
Optional<ClassA> findClassA(long id);
```

But when I run the code I keep getting this error:

> Instance factory 'public
> com.blah.ClassA(com.blah.ClassB,java.lang.String)'
> parameter '[classB]' has no matching columns in the result set.
> Verify that the Java compiler is configured to emit parameter names,
> that your result set has the columns expected, annotate the parameter
> names explicitly with @ColumnName, or annotate nullable parameters as
> @Nullable
> Blockquote
> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and found your post when trying to solve it. Incase you still haven't found a workaround, what I did was use mutable mapperobjects so that I was able to use BeanMapper instead of ConstructorMapper, which I then passed to my immutable @Value objects after doing the reduction.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a row reducer. With a join you will get the same A for every B (that is for an left join the default). You have an inner join so not sure if that is true for this case but I think your problem will be solved with a row reducer. Something like this:

```
    class AReducer implements LinkedHashMapRowReducer<Integer, ClassA> {
    @Override
    public void accumulate(Map<Integer, ClassA> map, RowView rowView) {
        ClassA a = map.computeIfAbsent(
                rowView.getColumn("id", Integer.class),
                id -> rowView.getRow(ClassA.class));

        final ClassB b= rowView.getRow(ClassB.class);
        if (b != null ) {
            a.setB(b);
        }
    }
}
```

and add the reducer to your method:

```
     @UseRowReducer(AReducer.class)
```